# qTranslate remove default directory from link

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, plugin-qtranslate

/ru - default directory, how can I remove it

this link: https://cambridge.ua/ru/teachers/ 
should be: https://cambridge.ua/teachers/

```
<ul class="language-chooser language-chooser-text 
qtranxs_language_chooser" id="qtranslate-chooser">
    <li class="lang-ru active"><a href="https://cambridge.ua/ru/teachers/" 
hreflang="ru" title="RU (ru)" class="qtranxs_text qtranxs_text_ru">
<span>RU</span></a></li>
    <li class="lang-en"><a href="https://cambridge.ua/en/teachers/" 
hreflang="en" title="EN (en)" class="qtranxs_text qtranxs_text_en">
<span>EN</span></a></li>
    <li class="lang-uk"><a href="https://cambridge.ua/uk/teachers/" 
hreflang="uk" title="UK (uk)" class="qtranxs_text qtranxs_text_uk">
<span>UK</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="qtranxs_widget_end"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to general plugin's options - `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=qtranslate-x#general` and in section "URL Modification Mode" choose "Pre-Path Mode" and then also check "Hide URL language information for default language" - like this:

[image]

Comment: this modification only for url, if I go to inspect element its steel got /ru

Comment: Without the magic `/ru` in the address `https://cambridge.ua/ru/teachers/` you won't be able to change the language version back to `ru`.